# Gem revision control information

Tags: origen-sdk

Other then peering into my .origen directory, is there any mechanism to get a Gem's source revision control system information?

The Gemfile obviously contains the version to use, but when doing development work it would be useful to be able to automate getting a local copy.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good indeed to automate that, but nothing like that is really provided right now.
In an earlier internal version of Origen we used to be able to do something like `origen fetch some_plugin` and it would go and fetch the source, though it was never quite as elegant as also adding the required path reference to your Gemfile to use the local copy once it was fetched.

However, the operation of that relied on an internal server we had to track what plugins we had available and where they lived.
Potentially it would be possible to build something similar that worked by talking to rubygems.org to get the metadata about where a gem lives.

Or maybe even just a command that copied an installed gem/plugin's source to an applications `tmp` directory and setup the required linkage in the `Gemfile` might be good enough?

Generally I don't feel great pain over not having such a command. I just have `Code/github/` and `Code/bitbucket` directories in my home dir to store copies of all the plugins I might commonly touch, then it is a pretty simple matter to just edit the Gemfile by hand whenever I want to make some debug/development changes.

As you probably know though, hand hacking the contents of your local gem copies in `.origen` is a bad idea and could lead to hard to trace bugs if you forget to roll the edits back!